# grizzly does not log Exceptions in requests

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, error-logging, grizzly

I've set up a simple jersey server like this:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example.jersey_test/services");
HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(API_URI), rc);
```

And I have a bean that simply throws an exception:

```
@Path("persons")
public class PersonService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getPersons() {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "test");
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
}
```

The log output is the following (so logging works, but the exception is not logged):

```
Jul 01, 2014 10:19:33 PM com.example.jersey_test.services.PersonService getPersons
INFO: test
```

The response is a 500 with looks like the following (so the stacktrace is not included):

[image: grizzly 500 error]

As [this answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329733/grizzly-standalone-logging), grizzly should be using the default logging API. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a way to start a grizzly server that both logs and prints out exceptions in the response:

```
HttpServer server =
    GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(getBaseURI(),
    Collections.singletonMap("javax.ws.rs.Application",
    "class.that.extends.ResourceConfig"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception doesn't come to Grizzly, it's getting processed by Jersey.
Grizzly has no information about the error other than provided by Jersey via:

**Response.sendError(int code, String description)**

where Jersey passes (500, "Request failed.")

Comment: Thank you, that confirms what I guessed from looking at the code. I now registered an exception mapper which logs the exception